# Exception starting filter richfaces java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Tags: java, tomcat6, java-6

```
JDK 1.6 with Tomcat 6 Server. When Run with Tomcat 6 Server, Found Exception starting richfaces. The External libraries files are included in "Java Build Path" with richfaces 3.2.1.GA Jar files.
```

**Console Error Message:**

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter richfaces
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Filter mapping for chameleon filter richfaces do not contain wilcard prefix or suffix
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.WebXml.setFilterName(WebXml.java:432)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.WebXml.init(WebXml.java:182)
        at org.ajax4jsf.resource.InternetResourceService.init(InternetResourceService.java:130)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.init(BaseFilter.java:181)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:424)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Apr 4, 2019 4:31:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart


Add  ajax4jsf-1.1.1.jar and richfaces-3.0.1.jar Files in Tomcat6/lib Folder
```

**Web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.resourceOptimization.enabled

</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
  </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Remove the <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> from web.xml file.

Comment: Not working. show error message:
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/dls_frontend/WEB-INF/web.xml
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter mapping must specify either a <url-pattern> or a <servlet-name>

Comment: Write servlet name without spaces

Comment: Thank you, it worked.

More Error Message is show as below

SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Comment: Same Error Message Shown after Clean & Built Project 
Servlet Name already Updated without spaces.but below Error Message is shown. Any body help

SEVERE: Exception starting filter richfaces
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Filter mapping for chameleon filter richfaces do not contain wilcard prefix or suffix